# Jquery: How to assign a JSON value to a function call

Tags: jquery, json

Before you go saying this is a duplicate or even closing it, please read the entire post.  I've searched on here and what I am trying to do is different than what is posted on this site.  The difference is, I am trying to assign a value from a JSON call to a function (one of several similar functions) so I can add the numbers returned for a total.

So if I have a JSON call like this:

```
var count;
function getMainContactCount {
    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
       count = data;
       c= getCount(count);
       return c;
    });
}

function getCount(count) {
    return count;
}
```

Please note that my second function says return count not alert count.  This works fine with alert because alert happens immediately and apparently return does not.

Then in my document ready (the above scripts are in an attached script file), I do this:

```
c= getMainContactCount();
count = getCount(c);
```

This clearly isn't going to work, but this is the essence of what I need to do.  I need in my document ready to be able to return all of the counts from the database and then add them together.  There are about 10 tables, so it seemed easier to return all the values into the document ready and then add them.  But this may not be the right approach.  What I don't want to do is alert the values, since that doesn't help me add the values.

Comment: What are you trying to do?  You cannot return from an AJAX call, they're async.

Comment: OK, well then how I get my value?  Again, I don't want to alert it.

Comment: The above follows several examples on here, but I need to find some way to get to the value other than alerting it.

Comment: you better simply write it with your server side code. e.g: `var count = <?php echo $count; ?>` where $count will be the thing you are trying to get from Ajax call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
var count;
function getMainContactCount {
    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
       count += data.length;
       // Whatever you you need to do with count, do it here.
       // Like this:
       alert(count) // just checking if we have the right value
                    // couldn't resist adding an alert :)
    });
}
```

**EDIT**

To reuse the same callback, define it outside the `getJSON` call:

```
 // Define a global count var
 var count;
 // Define a single callback to reuse
 var addCount = function(data) {
     count += data.length;
     alert(count); // just a test, remove the alert later
 }
 // Do several ajax calls to the json
 $.getJSON('/some_url', addCount);
 $.getJSON('/some_other_url', addCount);
 $.getJSON('/yet_another_url', addCount);
```

Comment: Again, I need to be able to have multiple similar functions, each with its own JSON call.  If I have to have multiple JSON calls, having the count inside the JSON call doesn't do me any good.

Comment: That's what I was looking for.  Thanks, bfavaretto!

Answer (score 0):

First off, `getJSON` is asynchronous. So `getMainContactCount` actually does not return anything.

Secondly, `count = getCount(c)` is equivalent to `count = c`.

What are you trying to do here?

If you want to get a value then use it later, split up your script execution, on load

```
var myPageLoadingScripts = function(count){  
  //You can use count here.  
  ...
}

$(function(){
    $.getJSON(url, myPageLoadingScripts);
});
```

Comment: I need to be able to assign the count to a variable in the body of my script.

Comment: So count is computed in the second function?